# How do I get the for loop the reset?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a python password guesser. I have made it where it splits the password you enter into multiple parts. Each part is 3 characters (or less). The guesser than guesses the parts individually. I got it to guess one part of the password. I think the for loop has to reset and do the same thing just with the new part, but I do not exactly know how to do that. I have searched the internet and found multiple people with the same problem, but I could not seem to implement it into my code.

I have searched the internet and found multiple people with the same problem, but I could not seem to implement it into my code.

```
from random import randint
import time

LettersAndSymbols = [
    "A",
    "a",
    "B",
    "b",
    "C",
    "c",
    "D",
    "d",
    "E",
    "e",
    "F",
    "f",
    "G",
    "g",
    "H",
    "h",
    "I",
    "i",
    "J",
    "j",
    "K",
    "k",
    "L",
    "l",
    "M",
    "m",
    "N",
    "n",
    "O",
    "o",
    "P",
    "p",
    "Q",
    "q",
    "R",
    "r",
    "S",
    "s",
    "T",
    "t",
    "U",
    "u",
    "V",
    "v",
    "W",
    "w",
    "X",
    "x",
    "Y",
    "y",
    "Z",
    "z",
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "5",
    "6",
    "7",
    "8",
    "9",
    "0",
]

print("Do NOT put a personal password")
ClientPassword = input("Please enter a password to test\n")

Guess = ""
num = 0
startTime = time.time()

c = 3
list = [ClientPassword[i:i+c] for i in range(0, len(ClientPassword), c)]
n=0
e = len(list)
reset = True


while Guess != list[n-1]:
  Guess = ""
  for letter in range(len(list[n])):
    GuessLetter = LettersAndSymbols[randint(0, 61)]
    Guess = str(GuessLetter) + str(Guess)
    if Guess == list[n] and n!=e:
      n+=1

executionTime = (time.time() - startTime)

print("Cracked password in",round(executionTime, 1),"second(s)! \nPassword was:","".join(list))
```

Comment: Wrap another loop around it?

Comment: Never use `list` as a variable name.  Doing so blocks the builtin.  Also, `str(s)` is just `s` if `s` is a string.  Don't throw in useless calls to convert strings to themselves.  You might just as well do `str(str(str(str(str(s)))))` for all the good it does.

Comment: As a side note, you could shorten your code significantly by importing the `string` module and then creating an equivalent list of alphanumeric letters by `LettersAndSymbols = string.ascii_letters + string.digits`.

Comment: As a second site note, you should really have a look at the naming conventions in the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 0):

You should divide the code into 2 while loops, the first loop is to test the overall result, and the second loop is to test each part of the result (which contains 3 chars or less). After each part is guessed right, added to the original variable using +=

Please check my code below. I commented and printed the result to see what going on in each loop. You could test with a simple pass like "abcd"

```
from random import randint
import time

LettersAndSymbols = [
    "A",
    "a",
    "B",
    "b",
    "C",
    "c",
    "D",
    "d",
    "E",
    "e",
    "F",
    "f",
    "G",
    "g",
    "H",
    "h",
    "I",
    "i",
    "J",
    "j",
    "K",
    "k",
    "L",
    "l",
    "M",
    "m",
    "N",
    "n",
    "O",
    "o",
    "P",
    "p",
    "Q",
    "q",
    "R",
    "r",
    "S",
    "s",
    "T",
    "t",
    "U",
    "u",
    "V",
    "v",
    "W",
    "w",
    "X",
    "x",
    "Y",
    "y",
    "Z",
    "z",
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "5",
    "6",
    "7",
    "8",
    "9",
    "0",
]

print("Do NOT put a personal password")
ClientPassword = input("Please enter a password to test\n")

num = 0
startTime = time.time()

c = 3
list1 = [ClientPassword[i:i+c] for i in range(0, len(ClientPassword), c)]
n=0
e = len(list1)
reset = True

print(list1)

# First create a GuessAll variable which contain the final answer (ex "abcd")
GuessAll = ""
while GuessAll != ClientPassword: # Only stop when guess result equal to the answer (ex "abcd")
    print(f"GuessAll: {GuessAll}")
    # Then guess for each part, for ex 2 parts "abc" and "d"
    for Part in list1:
        print(f"Part: {Part}")
        GuessPart = ""
        while GuessPart != Part: # Only stop when guesspart result equal to the part (ex "abc" or "d")
            GuessPart = ""
            for i in range(len(Part)):
                GuessLetter = LettersAndSymbols[randint(0, len(LettersAndSymbols)-1)]
                GuessPart += GuessLetter # add random letter to GuessPart ulti it reach a specific range
            print(f"GuessPart: {GuessPart}")
            print('+++++++++++++++++++')
        GuessAll += GuessPart # add the each part's result to GuessAll variable (ex "" => "abc" => "abcd")
        print(f"GuessAll: {GuessAll}")
executionTime = (time.time() - startTime)

print("Cracked password in",round(executionTime, 1),"second(s)! \nPassword was:","".join(list1))
# GuessAll: abcd
# Cracked password in 0.6 second(s)!
# Password was: abcd
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps out quite a bit!

Comment: @TheNeverEndingError If it works for you, please accept or upvote. If you have any questions feel free to ask